# C++ access trusted root certificates

Tags: c++, windows, certificate, private-key, cryptoapi

I have created a public/private key pair with openSSL and converted it into a `*.pfx` file with openSSL. I then imported this file into the `Windows Trusted Certificate Store`.

I now would like to access the private key from this certificate via c++ code.
Is this possible? If yes, can you please point me into a direction? I haven't found anything suitable yet.

Comment: Lots of reading:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380255(v=vs.85).aspx    _"CryptoAPI is intended for use by developers of Windows-based applications that will enable users to create and exchange documents and other data in a secure environment, especially over nonsecure media such as the Internet. Developers should be familiar with the C and C++ programming languages and the Windows programming environment. Although not required, an understanding of cryptography or security-related subjects is advised."_

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to access the private key.

[CertEnumCertificatesInStore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376050(v=vs.85).aspx) returns [PCCERT_CONTEXT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377189(v=vs.85).aspx)  structure which contain the encoded and decoded representations of certificates. Passing this structure to the [CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379885(v=vs.85).aspx) obtains the private key from the certificate

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look into it.